# Find two divisors of m, d1>1 and d2>1 where gcd(d1+d2, m)=1

Tags: python, algorithm, math, factors

I was attempting the question [Two Divisors](https://codeforces.com/contest/1366/problem/D) question on CodeForces. And it needed to calculate the prime factor for the answer.

But somehow even after the implementation of the Eratosthenes algorithm, my code shows TIME LIMIT EXCEEDED. Following is my code for reference. I would be very grateful if any help can be provided.

```
def eratosthenes(n):
    l=[]

    status=[1 for i in range(n+1)]
    for i in range(2,n+1):
        if status[i]:
            if n%i==0:
                l.append(i)
            for j in range(i*i, n+1, i):
                status[j]=0
    # print(l)
    return l

n = int(input())
arr = list(map(int, input().split()))
l1 = [-1 for i in range(n)]
l2 = [-1 for i in range(n)]

for i in range(n):
    primeDivisors= (eratosthenes(arr[I]))
    # print(primeDivisors)
    if len(primeDivisors)<=1:
        continue

    l1[i]=primeDivisors[0]
    l2[i]=primeDivisors[1]


for i in range(n):
    print(l1[i],end=" ")
print()
for i in range(n):
    print(l2[i],end=" ")
```

#### Problem statement

You are given n integers a1,a2,…,an.

For each ai find its two divisors d1>1 and d2>1 such that gcd(d1+d2,ai)=1 (where gcd(a,b) is the greatest common divisor of a and b) or say that there is no such pair.

Input

The first line contains single integer n (1≤n≤5⋅10^5) — the size of the array a.

The second line contains n integers a1,a2,…,an (2≤ai≤10^7) — the array a.

Output

To speed up the output, print two lines with n integers in each line.

The i-th integers in the first and second lines should be corresponding divisors d1>1 and d2>1 such that gcd(d1+d2,ai)=1 or −1 and −1 if there is no such pair. If there are multiple answers, print any of them.

Comment: In practice, you need to apply Sieve algorithm only once, for primes less than sqrt( max a)

Comment: You assume that you need to find all prime factors, but (1) the challenge does not ask for *prime* factors (unless you have proof that it is implied that solutions will always be possible using prime factors), and (2) you only need 2 of them. However, I do not see the gcd check in your code.

Comment: @trincot, it seems to me that we actually need only one prime factor and no GCD check.

Answer (score 1):

You are correct in using prime divisors. For coprime `p` and `q` (which primes necessarily are),

```
gcd(p + q, p*q) = 1
```

since if there were some prime that divided say `p` or `q` in `p*q` and divided `(p + q)`, it would necessarily divide both `p` and `q`, but that would contradict them being coprime.

Unfortunately, even if we were to choose prime `p` and `q`, we could not extend this statement to:

```
gcd(p + q, p^m * q^n * other_prime_powers) = 1
```

because a divisor of `other_prime_powers` could divide `(p + q)`, for example `gcd(3 + 11 = 14, 3*11*2) != 1`. (In our case, `p^m * q^n * other_prime_powers`, would be `A[i]`, the input element, and `p` and `q` are any two of its prime divisors that are greater than 1.)

But we *can* artificially construct a partition of all of `A[i]`'s prime powers, and then we could say,

```
gcd(a*b*c... + x*y*z..., a*b*c...*x*y*z...) = 1
```

since we have guaranteed that any divisor of `A[i]`, which divides one side of the partition, say `x*y*z...`, cannot divide both parts.

For each element, partition its prime powers into two arbitrary products; if the element is a prime power, set its answer to -1.

Technically, to create the partition, we only need to find one of `A[i]`s prime powers, P, then just divide `A[i]` by P.